# Share multiple times - UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, macos, uiactivityviewcontroller, mac-catalyst

When I try to share items using UIActivityViewController for the second time in my app (for example to Mail), I get the following error message:

`[ShareSheet] Cannot present share sheet without key host window`

How can I make it so that users can share multiple times? Now I users have to dismiss the view controller and open it again to share. Worth mentioning that this only happens on the Mac Catalyst version, iOS works as it should

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?
I'm encountering the same warning, within a Mac Catalyst app

Comment: Unfortunately not, I haven't spent much time investigating the issue after posting this. But will update the the post if I find a solution for it.